# TableViewer how to set caret position for the cell with Editing Support and remove FULL_SELECTION

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, caret, tablecelleditor

I have a TableViewer with last column which has EditingSupport to edit the cell's value. The viewer has style set to FULL_SELECTION.
Once I click on the cell, the text value is fully selected:

[image: "max value" is fully selected]

I can start editing, it will clear off the current value `"max value"` and start new value.

However, If i want to move the mouse to a specific position to edit, I need to give a delay of a sec or so. If I click too fast right after the first click to select, the cell will be deselected.

Is there any way to avoid that? Can I make the cell not fully selected ? or always have the caret to the end of the text ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `TextCellEditor` as the cell editor.

Create your own class extending `TextCellEditor` and override the `doSetFocus` class to be something like:

```
@Override
protected void doSetFocus()
{
  super.doSetFocus();

  if (text != null) {
     text.setSelection(0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: yes i do use `TextCellEditor`, and i just do a little modication as `text.setSelection( text.getText().length() );` to set the caret to end of the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to remove full selection and set caret to end of text, override `doSetFocus` and set `text.setSelection( text.getText().length() );`

to ignore double click event, override `getDoubleClickTimeout` to `return 0`